# How to catch socket exceptions on TcpInboundGateway?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `TcpInboundGateway` from `spring-integration` for a `socket` client.

In `TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage()` the stream is send via the socket connection. If an exception occurs eg because the socket is closed, there is just a spring error log `"Failed to send reply"`.

BUT I'd like to handle those socket errors explicit. How could I catch those errors in the desired class?

Comment: Use a custom `TcpInboundGateway` extending the original one and override `doOnMessage` to put a `try-catch` in?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that because it's a private method. You'd have to override `onMessage()`. But even that won't work because you need access to `connections` to lookup the connection so you'd have to override the `TcpSender` methods too.

Comment: Actually, see my (revised) answer, there is no point in overriding; this exception occurs on the inbound thread, not the replying thread. So you have to use the exception event mechanism to get notification of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>We should probably change that to propagate the exception, but it would be a behavior change so we'd probably have to do it in 4.2 only, unless we make it an option.</s>

Actually, after further review; this can't be accommodated - you have to handle the exception via the [connection exception event](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).

The send is performed on the inbound thread, not your send thread.

We could enhance the exception event to include the failed outbound message.

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, use a pair of [collaborating channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#d4e11967) instead of the inbound gateway.

That way, the send is performed on the thread that sends the reply and you can catch exceptions.

Comment: I would suggest you could make the `private boolean doOnMessage()` return `true` if there was no error (thus after `connection.send(reply)` - I wonder why this is not already the case), and `false` on exception. Currently it returns *always* false! Then make it `protected` so that we could override it, calling `super.DoOnMessage()` inside and evaluate the boolean. If false, it means there has been some kind of error returning the reply to the socket and could be handled accordingly?

Comment: It would be even nicer if you could return a `SimpleEntry<Boolean, Message<?>>` as a boolean result state and the `reply` as value, so that the overriding method can access the object that was do be send on send failures `if (!getKey())`.

Comment: As I said, it won't help you because the `doOnMessage` is called on the inbound thread that received the message, not on your thread that sent the reply - that is a fundamental framework design and will be difficult to change. The solution is to listen for the exception event. I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3745) to add the message to the event.

Comment: That might be correct in general, but I tried the following: open the client socket > send data to the socket > terminate the socket from the other side > try to send the reply over the socket. Result: `doOnMessage()` will evaluate `connection == null`, log an error and return `false`. But that's exactly the case I'd like to catch.

Comment: I see, yes, we should generate an event in that case too. There's not really much point in allowing you to subclass because this is running on a private thread in the gateway, so you'd have to hand it off somehow anyway, and the event mechanism should suffice for that.

Comment: OK that sounds great, I added this as a comment in jira.